# very simple javascript failing

Tags: php, javascript

Working Example:

This is almost identical to code I use in another places on my page but fails here for some reason.

```
<?php
//$p = "test";
?>

<script>
alert('posts are firing? ');
parent.document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = "test";
</script>
```

Failing example: (alert still works)

```
<?php
$p = "test of the var";
?>

<script>
alert('posts are firing? ');
parent.document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = '<?php $p; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `json_encode` if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
'<?php echo $p; ?>';
```

or

```
'<?= $p ?>';
```

Comment: Remember: You have to enable short_tags in your php.ini file for <?= to work :)

Comment: Yes, that is why I provided both lines :-)

Answer (score 2):

Debugging 101:  Start checking all variable values.

```
alert(parent);
alert(parent.document);
alert(parent.document.getElementById('posts'));
```

as well as the value rendered by:  `'<?php $p; ?>'`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your 'posts' object (I guess it is DIV or SPAN) loads before you fill it using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to generate javascript with php, here I use a simple echo:

```
<?php

$p = "test of the var";

echo"
<div id='posts'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var posts = document.getElementById('posts');
posts.innerHTML = '$p';
</script>
";

?>
```

Note the $p and that the div is printed before the javascript!

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting the variable data is why it isn't working. You need to echo or print the variable $p.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the $p is being evaluated, not printed.

To print it you should use **print**, **echo**, or the syntax <\?=$p;?>. without the \